# Better way to add and remove Objects in game than ArrayCopy

Tags: java, android, arrays, iteration

I’m working on a 2D game and using SurfaceView/Canvas to display my Bitmaps on screen. The Bitmaps are constantly added and removed from the canvas. At the moment I store all the Bitmaps that have to be drawn in an ArrayCopy, so I can add and remove objects although the List is iterated almost permanently. This works fine, but I’m not Sure if there might be a better/faster option.  Is there?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Canvas, you can call their createBufferStrategy() method to obtain a BufferStrategy-object and then you can use that to draw on another buffer then the one that is momentarily displayed. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferStrategy.html for reference.